# Base64 decode byte array - APNS token from iOS

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am receiving a device token, encoded as a base64 "byte" array.  The input looks like this:

```
J6Kwrh15AqXKiaQminI/Eb/Mtj4nMkPhQYsROhJXmes=
```

I am told this is a base64 encoded value, but decoding it using `base64_decode` returns:

```
string(32) "'¢°®y¥Ê‰¤&Šr?¿Ì¶>'2CáA‹:W™ë"
```

I found this script somewhere which should be outputting the actual APNS token:

```
$a = base64_decode("J6Kwrh15AqXKiaQminI/Eb/Mtj4nMkPhQYsROhJXmes=");
$b = array();

foreach(str_split($a) as $c)
    $b[] = sprintf("%08b", ord($c));

exit(implode(' ', $b));
```

But it returns:

```
00100111 10100010 10110000 10101110 00011101 01111001 00000010 10100101 11001010 10001001 10100100 00100110 10001010 01110010 00111111 00010001 10111111 11001100 10110110 00111110 00100111 00110010 01000011 11100001 01000001 10001011 00010001 00111010 00010010 01010111 10011001 11101011
```

And I'd expect something like:

```
c9d4c07c fbbc26d6 ef87a44d 53e16983 1096a5d5 fd825475 56659ddd f715defc
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a hex, you could use something like this:

```
$a = unpack("H*", base64_decode("J6Kwrh15AqXKiaQminI/Eb/Mtj4nMkPhQYsROhJXmes="));
print_r($a);
```

(`$a` is now an array with your hex)

To include the spacing you could use:

```
$a = unpack("H*hex", base64_decode("J6Kwrh15AqXKiaQminI/Eb/Mtj4nMkPhQYsROhJXmes="));
$b = str_split($a["hex"], 8);
$output = "";
foreach ($b as $current) {
    $output .= "$current ";
}
echo($output);
```

and finally everything wrapped into a function:

```
function base64_decode_apns_token($token) {
    $a = unpack("H*hex", base64_decode($token));
    $b = str_split($a["hex"], 8);
    $output = "";

    foreach ($b as $current) {
        $output .= "$current ";
    }

    return trim($output);
}
```

Comment: Sorry-- this does not work. See fiddle: http://ideone.com/rd0mHR - they all return the same output

Comment: If this can help: "The token is an opaque binary data structure, stuffed into an NSData object. Apple doesn’t want you to mess around with its internals. For our purposes it is enough to know that it is currently 32 bytes long. As you can see above, the token can be represented by 64 hexadecimal characters. You will be using it in that format, although you still strip off the brackets and leave out the spaces."

Comment: Well, of course your code doesn't work, if your function decodes the same token every time! (Pls look at my answer)

Comment: LOL. Sorry. That was horrible. Thanks.